# Use collapse key for 2 type ofmessages gcm

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

In my gcm android app I am sending 2 types of messages from application server.I got the idea about what is collapse key, but Idont know how to use.These are the two types of messages.
1.

```
$message = array(
        "price" => "signal",
        "type" => $user_type,
        "date" => $date1,
        "name" => $signal_name,
        "buy" => $price,
        "stop" => $stop,
        "tv" => $trig_value,
        "tp" => $profit,       
        "res" => $result,
    );
```

second one

```
$message = array(
      "price" => "instru",
      "price1" => $trade1,
       "price2" => "$trade2",
      "price3" => "$trade3",
      "price4" => "$trade4",
      "price5" => "$date"
   );
```

What I need is the last messages send for both of the message types persist in gcm server.How can I do that.I am giving the gcm class also .Please help.

GCM.php

```
<?php



class GCM {

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `collapse_key` parameter to your JSON.

The JSON should look like this :

For example, for the first type :

```
{ 
  "registration_ids":["...", "..."],
  "collapse_key": "type1",
  "data": {
        "price" => "...",
        "type" => "...",
        ...
  },
}
```

For the second type, give a different value to `collapse_key`.

Based on your code and my limited knowledge of PHP, you need something like this :

```
    $fields = array(
        'collapse_key' => $collapse_key,
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );
```

And the `$collapse_key` should be initialized based on the type of data you have in `$message`.